# how to prevent the innerHTML of change again after the click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let player1 = document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML;
let player2 = document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML;

let turn = 0
let blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("blocks");

for (let i of blocks) {
  i.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    i.innerHTML = turn
    if (turn == 0) {
      event.target.innerHTML = player1
      turn = 1
    } else {
      event.target.innerHTML = player2
      turn = 0
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <div id="0" class="blocks"></div>
    <div id="1" class="blocks"></div>
    <div id="2" class="blocks"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="3" class="blocks"></div>
    <div id="4" class="blocks"></div>
    <div id="5" class="blocks"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="6" class="blocks"></div>
    <div id="7" class="blocks"></div>
    <div id="8" class="blocks"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="player1" class="players"></div>
<div id="player2" class="players"></div>
```

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, you would only like the innerHTML to be changed once per block i?

Comment: Please explain your problem in the question. The title should just be a brief summary.

Comment: yea, cause, if i put the player1 content in a block and then click again on it, the innerHTML changes to player2. I wander to click once and then the innerHTML can be changed only on a page reload, got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test for `innerHTML` first to see if there is already somethign in there...

```
if (i.innerHTML.trim() != '') return;
```

```js
let player1 = document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML;
let player2 = document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML;
let turn = 0
let blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("blocks");
for (let i of blocks){
i.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
    if (i.innerHTML.trim() != '') return;
    i.innerHTML = turn 

    if (turn == 0){
        event.target.innerHTML = player1
        turn = 1
    }
    else {event.target.innerHTML = player2
    turn = 0}

})
}
```

```css
.blocks {
padding:20px;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid #666;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
 <div>
        <div id="0" class="blocks"></div>
        <div id="1" class="blocks"></div>
        <div id="2" class="blocks"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div id="3" class="blocks"></div>
        <div id="4" class="blocks"></div>
        <div id="5" class="blocks"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="6" class="blocks"></div>
        <div id="7" class="blocks"></div>
        <div id="8" class="blocks"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="player1" class="players"></div>
<div id="player2" class="players"></div>
```

Comment: it seems worked perfectly for what i wanted, but i dont get it the "if (i.innerHTML.trim() != '') return;" line, i will search on it, thank you.

Comment: That line is what prevents it from changing on-click after the first click. It says 'if the contents of that element (innerHTML) - after removing any white space (trim()) is NOT empty (meaning, it has a little emoji face in it) - THEN return (not allow the function to continue)

Comment: you used the "return" for stop the function to continue, i didnt knew this can be done, thank you.